# Riemannian metric. Help with notation.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was just reading about the hyperbolic space (upper-half plane model) and i'm getting kind of
confused about the notation for the Riemannian metric. The half-plane is defined as
$$
H = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y > 0\},
$$
and the metric is defined as 
$$
ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}.
$$
I've just taken a first course in Riemannian geometry and I have absolutely no idea where this notation comes from and what it means. We usually defined metrics explicitely as some bilinear map $g$. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At each point $(x,y)\in H$, the tangent space $T_pH$ at $p$ is nothing but spanned by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, i.e. every tangent vector at $p$ is in the form of $a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

With this understanding, the Riemannian metric $g=ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}$ means the following 
$$g(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=\frac{dx^2(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x})}{y^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$
and 
$$g(\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=\frac{dy^2(\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})}{y^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$
and
$$g(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=0$$
since there is no $dxdy$ term. And these are extended linearly, i.e. 
$$g(a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y},c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+d\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=ac\,g(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x})+(ad+bc)g(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})+bd\,g(\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=...$$

Comment: I was also struggling with this (for the same example). More generally, assuming an $n$-dimensional manifold, what you are saying is that the term $dx_{i_{1}}\cdots dx_{i_{n}}$ is the linear functional which equals $1$ on $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_{1}}},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_{n}}})$ and $0$ on all other $n$-tuples in the elements $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n}}\}$, right? How does the example differ from $\frac{dx\wedge dx+dy\wedge dy}{y^{2}}$?